# Why is a message interrupting subtotaling code?

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a message that pops up with my code when trying to subtotal:

"Microsoft Excel cannot determine which row in your list or selection contains column labels, which are required for this command. If you want the first row of the selection or list used as labels and not as data, click OK."

Nothing else (such as sorting that exact range) has trouble identifying the header.
As soon as I click “OK,” the code continues and the result is fine. However, I don’t like the interruption or understand why this is happening. The actual code is something like:

```
Range(“A1:Z” & variable).Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

Any advice is sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before adding the subtotals

Comment: Avoid blank cells on the first line of the range